# Как наложить картинку на фон с цветом rgb?

Tags: html, css

В общем, проблема такая. Есть фон, градиентовский. Поверх него нужно наложить картинку svg, да так, что бы они вместе совпали, и картинка svg приняла тот цвет. Вот пример:

[image: Сам пример]

Как видите, картинка градиентовская. Пытался сделать через `background-blend-mode` , но он мне позволил лишь сделать так, как нужно, но только загвоздка в том, что наложить можно лишь один цвет. Вот как это у меня получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался сделать градиент через свойство `background`, но в этом случае картинка не отображается, а отображается лишь в том случае, когда прописываю через свойство `background-color`.

Вот сам код:

```
.ready_btns {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;


background-blend-mode: color-burn;
background-image: url(https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/602787a8a1e988ce61a0a453/602787a9abcefc3c6b0a8f86_wavy-bg.svg);
background-position: top;
background-color: #350e47;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

}

Буду благодарен за поддержку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот как-то так - [codepen](https://codepen.io/grdnk/pen/eYBgLvZ)

```
background-image: url("..."), linear-gradient(pink, blue);
background-image: url("..."), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(pink), to(blue));
background-image: url("..."), -moz-linear-gradient(top, pink, blue);
```